# Disabling a Button with an icon

Tags: android, android-button

I have a simple Button, which has a drawable set as icon:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/bOk"
     android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_ok"
     android:text="@string/ok"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

when I disable the button, either in XML layout file:    `android:enabled="false"`

or programmaticaly: `bOk.setEnabled(false);`

The button gets disabled, it is 'grayed out', but the icon remains as it was ine the enabled state.

[image]

How can I get a look, that the icon is also 'grayed out'?

Comment: set a different icon, while disabling it.

Comment: Automatically does not change icon color you have to change the icon when make disable button

Comment: Prepare two different icon pictures，and then write in a `<selector/>` to set different drawable according to different enable state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new grayed icon and add both inside a `selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ok" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ok_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />

</selector>
```

Use inside button like: `android:drawableStart="@drawable/selector"`

For **TextColor**,

Create another selector inside `res/color/mycustomtextcolor.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="#666" android:state_enabled="false" /> 
  <item android:color="#000" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

Inside your widget call using: `android:textColor="@color/mycustomtextcolor"`

Or

inside your `style` add another item using: `<item name="android:textColor">@color/mycustomtextcolor</item>`

Comment: I like this solution the most. But, could you help me further more? 
How do I deal with the textColor the same way? My color is set via @styles.

Comment: I have added code for textColor too. Hope it helps.

Comment: Of course it helps! I was able to set the background the same way. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Happy to help!!

Answer (score 2):

Like a regular Button, a Button that has an image background is not grayed when disabled.

You have to use another image it appears grayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_gray" /> ***button_gray is a Drawable image***
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_gray" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_red" /> ***button_red is a Drawable image*** 
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tint your drawable on enabled and disabled state using a selector with bitmaps:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon_ok" android:tint="@color/disableColorWithAlpha" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon_ok" android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
    </item>
</selector>
```